# Select the first span element which is not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

From a group of span elements, I want to get the values of the first occurrence of a span that is not empty.

I have this HTML

```
<span class="map_multi_latitude"></span>
<span class="map_multi_longitude"></span>
<span class="map_multi_latitude">30.201998</span>
<span class="map_multi_longitude">120.990876</span>
```

I have this Jquery before but I want to make it work such that "the first span whose text is not empty":

```
initialLat = $('span.map_multi_latitude:first').text();
initialLng = $('span.map_multi_longitude:first').text();
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This will work:

```
$('span:not(:empty):first').text()
```

or these:

```
$('span:not(:empty):eq(0)').text()
$('span:not(:empty)').eq(0).text()
$('span:not(:empty)').slice(0,1).text()
$('span:not(:empty)').first().text()
```

Comment: this appears to only work if there are more than one spans which are not empty. if there is only one span which is not empty, this fails

Comment: @Ygam: Works fine with one non-empty span. Be aware that empty means truly empty. In other words, no white space.

Comment: A custom filter function can be used to throw away elements that contain nothing or whitespace only: `$('span').filter(function(){return $(this).text().trim()}).first().text()`

Answer (score 2):

```
initialLat = $('span.map_multi_latitude:not(:empty):first').text();
initialLng = $('span.map_multi_longitude:not(:empty):first').text();
```

Comment: this appears to only work if there are more than one spans which are not empty. if there is only one span which is not empty, this fails

Comment: It should work regardless of number of elements. Check it http://jsfiddle.net/2B3PU/

Answer (score 0):

```
var firstMapMultiLatitude;
$('.map_multi_latitude').each(function (index, element) {
    if ($(element).val() != '') {
        firstMapMultiLatitude = $(element).val();
        alert($(element).val());
        return;
    }
});
```